# Nested IF(AND(OR statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my current formula

```
=IF(OM2=0,"No",IF(OM2=4(OR(5,11,12,16,17))*AND(F2="Double"),"Yes",IF(OM2=1(OR(2,3,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15))*AND(F2="Triple"),"Yes","No")))
```

I'm trying to get OU to be yes if OM is 4,5,11,12,16,or 17 and F is Double.
Also, to get OU to be yes if OM is 1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,13,or 15 and F is Triple.

I have checked F2 and it correctly  results "Double" or "Triple" accordingly with correct spelling and no extra spaces.

I am still getting "No" being resulted, see pic below:
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @DudeCoder don't agree, many of the questions on here are about logic in many different programs... so this question fits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write OR(OM2 = x, OM2=y, OM2 = z ...) instead of what you wrote.

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

As the other responders said you should really think about making a lookup tables.

In addition, if you use Excel 2013 onwards, it is much easier if you convert your normal table into "Excel" table (Ctrl - T will do it). Google more about "Excel tables" to learn about their benefits vs traditional tables.

After that, set up 2 lookup tables, Table 1 and Table 2 (they themselves should also be Excel tables) as in the photo.

Then your formula will be:

```
=OR(SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[OM]=[@OM]),--(Table1[F]=[@F])),SUMPRODUCT(--(Table2[OM]=[@OM]),--(Table2[F]=[@F])))
```

[image]

When you write up this formula, you can just select the cells in the respective lookup tables, Excel will automatically turn them into table named ranges as you see above.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a lookup table to map your value of `OM` to the expected value of `OU`.

For example, if you had a sheet named "Lookup" with the following data:

```
  | A | B
1 | 1 | Triple
2 | 2 | Triple
...   
5 | 5 | Double
```

Then you could use something like

```
IF(VLOOKUP(OM2,Lookup!$A$1:$B$16,2,FALSE)=OU2,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to keep it to one worksheet.

Comment: You can combine `ISERROR`, `MATCH` and an Array of values: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(OM2,{4,5,11,12,16,17},0))),"Yes","No")`